# How can I print web scraped text onto a single line?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape tracking information from a shipper website using beautifulsoup. However, the format of the html is not conducive to what I'm trying to do. There is unnecessary spacing included in the source code text which is cluttering up my output. Ideally I'd just like to grab the date here but I'll take "Shipped" and the date at this point as long as it's on the same line.

I've tried using .`replace(" ","")` & `.strip()` with no success.

Python Script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

TrackList = ["658744424"]


for TrackNum in TrackList:
    source = requests.get('https://track.xpoweb.com/en-us/ltl-shipment/'+TrackNum+"/").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    ShipDate = soup.find('p', class_="Track-meter-itemLabel text--center").text
    print(ShipDate)
```

HTML Source Code:

```
<p class="Track-meter-itemLabel text--center">
<strong class="text--bold">
                          Shipped
                        </strong>
                        5/23/2019
                      </p>
```

This is what's being returned. Additional spaces and blank lines.

```
                      Shipped

                    5/23/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
trac = [your html code above]
soup = BeautifulSoup(trac, "lxml")
soup.text.replace(' ','').replace('\n',' ').strip()
```

Output:

```
'Shipped  5/23/2019'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `stripped_strings` generator which is already built into BeautifulSoup but it's not common knowledge.

```
### Your code

for ShipDate in soup.find('p', class_="Track-meter-itemLabel text--center").stripped_strings:
    print(ShipDate)
```

Output:

```
Shipped
5/23/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

TrackList = ["658744424"]

for TrackNum in TrackList:
    source = requests.get('https://track.xpoweb.com/en-us/ltl-shipment/'+TrackNum+"/").text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    print(' '.join(re.sub(r'\s+',' ', soup.select_one('.Track-meter-itemLabel').text.strip()).split('\n')))
```